# Show tags and posts in the same page

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Basically in the posts index page, I'd like to show posts and related tags as well so that I can use them to filter. Normally a post has many tags and a tag could belong to many posts. This is bit of my code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    location: { refreshModel: true },
    page: { refreshModel: true },
  },

  model: function(params){
    return this.store.findQuery('post', params);
  }
});
```

The web service returns a json like:

```
{ posts: [
  {id: 1, title: "title", tags: [1, 2]}
], 
tags: [
  {id: 1, name: "Physics", posts: [1]}, 
  {id: 2, name: "Math", posts: [1]}
]}
```

To show all tags in the top of the page, I have a property in the Array controller which set tags:

```
setTags: function(){
  var str = "";
    this.store.all('tag').forEach(function(tag){
      str += tag.get('name') + ',';
  });
  this.set('tags', str);
}

# In template I use tags input to be able to filter posts by deleting tags:
{{tags-component value=tags}}
```

but as my model get refreshed using other filters such as location, page.. etc, some old tags stays in the store. So old and new tags appear (however I want to show only new one returned from server)

It seems to be like a typical issue, but I did not find something similar. Any resource how to implement it?

Comment: I actually don't understand your question. First you want to show all tags, later you want to show only some, but I don't understand which routes, actions etc. are supposed to be involved (or less technical, what the workflow in the UI is supposed to be). Could you elaborate? A Jsbin with a (partly ...) working example could be helpful as well.

Comment: @jnfingerle I actually want to show only the tags returned from server once model is refreshed because these one are related to the posts filtered (Never old ones or all), I copied some of the code in my original post, if you need any other piece please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as far as I know, there is no simple answer (but prove me wrong, if there is).

Instead of `this.store.all('tag')` in above code (which gives you all tags that are cached in the store) I'd iterate (each loop) over the posts, get each post's tags and put those tags in an identity map (a map or "hash" of id => object). This way you'd avoid duplicates. Now you would iterate over the values in the map to generate your string.

Comment: Totally right, I accept your answer that it did the trick actually. However I'd prefer a better solution. Since the web service returns only the actual tags, I was trying something like this.get('model.tags') or this.get('model').get('tags') but no way.